# Difficulty aligning xticks to edge of Histogram bin

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to show the frequency of my data throughout the hours of the day, using a histogram, in 3 hour intervals. I therefore use 8 bins.

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.hist(comments19['comment_hour'], bins = 8, alpha = 1, align='mid', edgecolor = 'white', label = '2019', density=True)
plt.title('2019 comments, 8 bins')
plt.xticks([0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24])
plt.xlabel('Hours of Day')
plt.ylabel('Relative Frequency')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

However, the ticks are not aligning with the bin edges, as seen from the image below.

[image: Histogram Matplotlib Image]

Comment: Aren't they off because the 8 boundary values and their own xticks are different? I'm judging from CODE as I haven't been able to run it in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `bins=8`, seaborn will set 9 evenly spread boundaries, from the lowest value in the input array (0) to the highest (23), so at `[0.0, 2.875, 5.75, 8.625, 11.5, 14.375, 17.25, 20.125, 23.0]`. To get the 9 boundaries at `0, 3, 6, ...` you need to set them explicitly.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')

comments19 = pd.DataFrame({'comment_hour': np.random.randint(0, 24, 100)})

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.hist(comments19['comment_hour'], bins=np.arange(0, 25, 3), alpha=1, align='mid', edgecolor='white', label='2019',
         density=True)
plt.title('2019 comments, 8 bins')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 25, 3))
plt.xlabel('Hours of Day')
plt.ylabel('Relative Frequency')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that your `density=True` means that the total area of the histogram is 1. As each bin is 3 hours wide, the sum of all the bin heights will be `0.33` and not `1.00` as you might expect. To really get a y-axis with relative frequencies, you could make the internal bin widths `1` by dividing the hours by `3`. Afterwards you can relabel the x-axis back to hours.

So, following changes could be made for all the bins to sum to 100 %:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

plt.hist(comments19['comment_hour'] / 3, bins=np.arange(9), alpha=1, align='mid', edgecolor='white', label='2019',
         density=True)
plt.xticks(np.arange(9), np.arange(0, 25, 3))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
```

[image: summing to 100%]

Comment: Thank you for the additional tips on the density! Would you say that the chart pre-adjustment is considered inaccurate? I also noticed that in your second pic there are 7 bins. is that an error or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: Thank you for notifying. The 7 bins were a typo: it should be `np.arange(9)` to get the numbers 0,1,..,8 (I mistakenly wrote `np.arange(8)`). Without adjustment the y-axis would be the relative frequency divided by 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can do either:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

# define the bin and pass to plt.hist
bins = [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24]
plt.hist(comments19['comment_hour'], bins = bins, alpha = 1, align='mid', 

# remove this line
# plt.xticks([0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24])
edgecolor = 'white', label = '2019', density=True)
plt.title('2019 comments, 8 bins')
plt.xlabel('Hours of Day')
plt.ylabel('Relative Frequency')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Or:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bins = np.arange(0,25,3)
comments19['comment_hour'].plot.hist(ax=ax,bins=bins)

# other plt format
```